# error with JSP/ Servlets progam when executing on port 8080:

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have moved my project into my webapps directory under the tomcat 6.0 directory and am running this under the updated url using port 8080. 
Has anyone ever seen this error?

```
**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\BIN\ocijdbc10.dll already loaded in another classloader**
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection$1.run(T2CConnection.java:3147)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.loadNativeLibrary(T2CConnection.java:3143)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:221)
oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:132)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:78)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I am curious to find out what the first line of this stack trace is. 
What does this mean?
Please let me know if more information is required from my program.
Thank you in advance.
Sonny

Comment: I agree with the first answer, your problem comes from the JDBC for Oracle DB, you're loading it directly from the oracle installation. Copy it to tomcat lib folder and reference it from that folder.

Answer (score 1):

As error saying - you can not load **dll** lirary from two separate `class loaders`. Most likely you have two separate Web Applications using connection to Oracle.
Please try to move oracle library **jar** to Tomcat `shared/lib` folder, so library will be loaded only once by **Tomcat Common Class Loader**.

Comment: I apologize in advance but I am a beginner in this. So you are saying take the ocijdbc10.dll from the oracle directory and put it in the tomcat directory, restart the tomcat server and it should work? Thanks in advance

Comment: No, dll file is loaded by Oracle Java API (you can see oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver in stack trace). You need to find jar with this class. Then put it to Tomcat folder and restart the server.

Comment: Ok. the only jar that I have that connects to oracle is the ojdbc14.jar file. I have cut that from the libraries folder in my project and pasted that into tomcat/lib and restarted the server and tried to execute the URL again. I am still getting the same error. It seems like this is the only jar that connects to oracle. Is there something I am missing? Should I find the other project that is using this library and delete it from there also? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, please check if some other web component use this library.

Comment: There are 4 other projects in the webapps directory and they all use the ojdbc14.jar. I don't think moving my jar to the tomcat/lib will do the trick if these other projects were not affected. Am I looking at this incorrectly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello all I solved my own issue. I had to change the path of the oracle database to a jdbc thin client url as opposed to directly connecting to the oracle database. 
originally I was using the statement: intfdb.JDBCOCIDRV=jdbc:oracle:oci:@GPSTRKPD.na.jnj.com
to connect which was causing the error. 
I change my statement to: jdbc:oracle:thin:@psgtwp0.na.jnj.com:1531:gpstrkpd and it works fine now. Thanks for all of your input.
Sonny